# Rswag: Authorization header appeared in query parameter

Tags: header, rswag

Version: rswag (2.0.5), rspec (3.8.0)

Environment: Rails 5.2.3, Ruby 2.4.5

It is my first time to use it, was stuck in authorization header for a day.
Here is what I did:

```
# in spec/swagger_helper.rb
  config.swagger_docs = {
    'api/v1/swagger.json' => {
      swagger: '2.0',
      info: {
        title: 'API V1',
        version: 'v1'
      },
      paths: {},
      securityDefinitions: {
        JWT: {
          description: 'the jwt for API auth',
          type: :apiKey,
          name: 'Authorization',
          in: :header
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```
# in spec/integration/api/v1/nodes_spec.rb
  path '/api/v1/nodes' do
    get 'Get all servers' do
      tags TAGS_NODE
      produces  'application/json'
      security [JWT: {}]

      parameter name: :searchString, in: :query, type: :string
      parameter name: :searchColumn, in: :query, type: :string
      #parameter name: 'Authorization', :in => :header, :type => :string
      let(:nodes) { create_list(:node_list, 32) }

      response '200', 'Servers found' do
        let(:'Authorization') { "Bearer #{gen_jwt}" }
        let(:searchString) { 'test' }
        let(:searchColumn) { ';Name;' }
        run_test! do |repsonse|
          data = JSON.parse(response.body)
          puts data
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Expected: The 'Bearer ....' is set in 'Authorization' header
Actual: In the test log, I found:

[INFO] [2019-09-29 01:11:13 UTC] [anony] [no session] [no req] [other other]Started GET "/api/v1/nodes?searchString=test&searchColumn=;Name;&params&**headers[HTTP_AUTHORIZATION]**=Bearer+eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1Njk3NjI2NzMsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEBpYm0uY29tIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9ucyI6WyJ0ZXN0X29yZzEiLCJvcmcyIl0sInJvbGVzIjpbImNjX2NvbnNvbGVfYWRtaW4iLCJyb2xlMiJdLCJpbnZlbnRvcnkiOlsidGVzdF9pbnYiXX0.eenTMWUy6kSHO58_kLKoKWmNjvQ9i5TU9ex4Ou-ausE&headers[HTTP_ACCEPT]=application%2Fjson" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-29 01:11:13 +0000
[INFO] [2019-09-29 01:11:13 UTC] [anony] [no session] [no req] [other other]Processing by Api::V1::NodesController#index as HTML
......
[DEBUG] [2019-09-29 01:11:13 UTC] [anony] [no session] [no req] [other other]Auth by JWT token....
[ERROR] [2019-09-29 01:11:13 UTC] [anony] [no session] [no req] [other other]**No JWT token included in request**

As marked as bold in the log, the 'Authorization' as well as 'Accept' headers are appeared in query parameters, which are supposed to be http headers, so that no JWT token can be retrieved from header in code.

I also tried not to use securityDefinition, but specify a parameter in header as following: parameter name: 'Authorization', :in => :header, :type => :string. It did not work either.

Not sure any configuration I missed, or something wrong I did? Thanks!

**Update**: it seems to be related to other gems conflict? I had another try to create a new Rails 5 api only app, add rspec and rswag gems only, and run with a simple test case, it worked! 
Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.4.5'

gem 'rails', '5.2.3'
gem 'puma', '3.11'
gem 'bootsnap', '1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
end

group :test do
  # Test framework
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "database_cleaner", '1.6.0'
  gem "simplecov"
  gem "simplecov-rcov"
  gem "factory_bot_rails", '5.1.0'
  gem "ci_reporter_rspec"
  gem "faker"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'pg', '1.1.4'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record', '4.1.3'
gem 'delayed_job_worker_pool', '0.2.3'

gem 'dalli', '2.7.8'
gem 'ruby-kafka', '0.7.5'

gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.10.10'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.7'
gem 'rest-client', '1.8.0'
gem 'symmetric-encryption', '4.3.0', require: false
gem 'unicorn', '5.2.0'
gem 'rubyzip', '1.2.2'
gem 'jwt', '2.2.1'
gem 'rubyXL', '3.3.30'
gem 'apartment', '2.2.1'
gem 'rswag', '2.0.5'
```

**[Resolved]**
Seems not working with Rack::Test::Methods

It worked after remove the line 'include Rack::Test::Methods" in a helper file, which was added previously to use 'get' to test the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not working with Rack::Test::Methods

It worked after remove the line 'include Rack::Test::Methods" in a helper file, which was added previously to use 'get' to test the API.